# set default fonts for Aquamacs in .emacs

Tags: fonts, aquamacs

I am running Aquamacs 3.3 under macOS Sierra (10.12.6).  The default fonts are way too small.  How can I do the equivalent of the following tedious procedure via code in my `.emacs`?

- `Options` Menu -> `Appearance` -> `font for LaTeX mode` (or whichever mode I'm in)
- The fonts window now pops up and I need to:

  - click `Monaco 18.0 pt`
  - click the `T` (for text colour) and then click the `black` icon (because in some modes it chooses white as the font colour by default...)
  - close the color window and the font window

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my `.emacs` was doing something that was incompatible with the default Aquamacs behaviour of saving font choices on Quit.  So... if somebody else ever runs across this problem, I suggest temporarily removing your `.emacs` and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: What were you doing that stopped this - Aquamacs is just using normal emacs functions to do the saving - so you might be breaking other things